# Conditional Format If the date is more than a year

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to apply a conditional format to Column J if in Column K the date is more than a year from Today. I have applied the following J2<=Today()-365 , however this is highlighting the entire column and is only validating for cell j2 how to validate for the entire column?

[image]

Comment: Your conditional format rule should be `=$K2<=TODAY()-365` to lock the column you want to check the date against.

Comment: @asongtoruin So I have changed my formula, now it won't highlight any cell, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have `J2`as the conditions - you want to make that `=K2<=Today()-365`.

But, since you have multiple columns, etc. and conditional formatting can get wonky quickly, I suggest anchoring the cell reference, `=$K2<=Today()-365` and make sure that rule applies to range `$J$2:$J$[lastRow]`.

Comment: I edited my formula, and applied my condition to $J$2:$J$5000 and it won't highlight

Comment: @Luis - The new formula is `=$K2<=Today()-365`?  What does your info look like, does it highlight *anywhere*?

Comment: I uploaded the new picture and I made sure my K column is date values

Comment: @Luis - Check your Conditional Formatting setup/range again (Range Manager). Sometimes after updating it, the formula can get wonky (like `=K229384 <= Today()-365`).  Can you screenshot it actually? It may help decipher the issue.

Comment: New Picture is put with the range

Comment: @Luis - If you choose "This Worksheet", instead of "Current Selection", does it change the range/formula at all, or is it still `K2` and range `J2:J5000`?

Comment: still the same range and formula....Also note I have other conditions and they are working